# Split Tunneling nmcli vpn pptp connection on vps

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, nmcli, pptp

**nmcli  vpn pptp connection  on vps**

When I create a pptp VPN connection my VPS connection is lost due to the change of the IP address.

Can I create a tunnel so that the server does not lose the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `ipip` tunnel (see `man ip-link`) and route its traffic either through (when available) or outside the VPN tunnel.

A severe downside of this may be that applications may not be able to detect any more whether their traffic is encrypted. Usually when you use tunnels the system is reachable only when the tunnel is up. That kind of solves your problem...

Comment: i do not understand that .. can you give me a full command . I am not good with Linux

Comment: I am looking for a way to allow  by vpn connection id

Comment: @Meaningsinminds Even I would have to look that up; I did that once for testing, feels like 10 years ago. This is advanced networking. If you are "not good with Linux" then this is not for you. I don't think there is a reasonably simple solution fpr your problem.